# How to substitute in a text file one line of another using find?

Tags: linux, replace, find

DISCLAIMER: I am not asking how to fix wordpress, I am asking on how to use `find` for a specific task.

I host a blog in the Wordpress platform. I've realized that I've been infected and now all my php files show a dirty header that breaks my installation. Fortunately I've realized that this is easy to clean. I just need to remove the first line of the php files, which contains the string `neeuczbkme` and substitute it with a normal php header `<?php`

First I created a file with the proper header string `<?php` and saved it as `~/fix`

I am trying to just `grep -v` all my php files, copy them to `~/tmp` then `cat ~/fix ~/tmp` and overwrite the original php file. If I do this manually it works very well but when I try to implement this idea using `find` I cannot do so.

I am trying

```
find plugins -iname "*.php" -exec grep -v neeuczbkme {} > ~/tmp \; -exec cat ~/fix ~/tmp > {} \;
```

This doesn't work... any ideas?

Comment: You should delete everything and restore from a backup. What if there are processes running (or cron-jobs) that modify your php files again...

Comment: I just did a search for `wordpress hacked fix` and got 120 answers. You can't fix this with a snap of your fingers, whatever was able to hack your code can still do it, unless you find and fix the root cause. Sorry, no easy answers. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. I've done all that before. I am just finding some php files that need to be cleaned. The rest of the installation is fresh. Please note that I am not asking "how to fix wordpress" but how to use `find`

Comment: turn all of your fileFixing activities into one small script and then use it like `find ...| xargs myFixer.sh` ? If any of your filenames have a space in them, then search here for `find printf0`. Good luck.